# Add/Removing value to array with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I have created a feature for the user to add and remove rows (PHP and JS).

I have declared my array of items outside of my functions. The problem that I have is when a remove a row, the number is not added back to the array.

Here is my code:

```
var maxField = 10
var x = 0; 

var idArray = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= maxField; i++) {
   idArray.push(i);
}

// sort the array as number, not as a string 
idArray = idArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (+a) - (+b);
});



$('#addItem').click(function() {

    x = idArray.shift();    // get the next available id in the idArray for the record

    if(x <= maxField) { 
        // do something 
    }
});


$('#removeItem').on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) { 

    var removeButtonId = this.id,
        splitRemoveButtonId = removeButtonId.split('_');
        x = splitRemoveButtonId[2]; 
        // get the value of x and put it back in the idArray, sort the array and be ready for the next record

        idArray.push(x); 

        idArray = idArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          return (+a) - (+b);
        });

        alert(x +' - '+ idArray);

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

I am using push() to add the items back to the array that is outside of my function but it is not working.  I have also tried concat() but it did not work. The row/item is removed but the value of that row, x, is not added back to the array.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Interestingly if I fill the array as follows everything works correctly.

```
idArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

The issue appears to be related to the for loop to fill the array - or - the code inside the removeItem function is not updating array.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= maxField; i++) {
   idArray.push(i);
}
```

**SOLVED:**

This was a simple issue that took me a while to solve. When x was added back to the array when the remove button was clicked, it was added as a string with double quotes. Adding the following solved the issue.

```
idArray = idArray.map(Number);
```

Comment: no need for unary plus, minus coerces strings to number. the assignment of the sorted array is ssuperfluous, because sort works in situ.

Comment: That's a complex system for creating IDs!  Why do you need them?

Comment: Please fix the quotes in the question. You have a curly quote in `$('#addItem’)` and you have both a curly quote and missing quote in `$(‘#removeItem).

Comment: I've submitted an edit, @Barmar

Comment: @Catch44 It should be edited by the OP, to make sure it matches his actual code.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the edit. I copy/pasted from text editor.

Comment: @Gman I didn't edit, I told Catch44 he should let you edit it. Please make sure the posted code matches the real code.

Comment: Make sure you have "smart quotes" turned off in your text editor when working with code. Even better would be to get an IDE that checks syntax, it won't do smart quotes.

Comment: @James I am creating a div that add/removes rows that allows a user to add items based on web services. They can add up to ten items but may need to remove (or edit and remove) items.  It's not as complicated as it seems. I'm just having a problem adding the id of the item removed back into the array.

Comment: You should consider not encoding the number into the string that is your id. Instead, use a `data-` attribute (like `data-id="0"`) to pull that information back out. Please do update your code here to show the HTML on which this code runs. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding IDs as much as possible when you are working with a list of similar items. Here is a generic example which lets the user add/remove very simple elements. The page manipulation is done solely with relative positioning.  Instead of building the section that gets added by creating and appending individual nodes, it clones a hidden node which is present in the html.

```js
$('#container').on('click', '.add', function () {
  if ($('.item').length <= 10) {
    var d = $('.item').first().clone();
    d.find('span').text('different text');
    d.css('display', '');
    $('#container').append(d);
  }
});

$('#container').on('click', '.remove', function () {
  $(this).closest('.item').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='item' style='display:none'>
    <span>some text</span>
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>    
  </div>
  <button class='add'>Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Hi James,
Thanks for this tip. 
I have a several tables on a page and each table has a <td> with a select dropdown menu. Based on the selection I need 4 <td> in that row to display a specific value/option.  
Do you think this would work as you describe above?
What is the best approach to do this?  Traversie td/tr with closest() ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Mike,
Sorry, just saw your message about data-id="0". Would this work in my case for table rows I mentioned above?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes this method works well for a grid of dropdowns or other input fields.  And for tables, make a tr that's hidden but populated with your dropdowns etc and clone that.